# Matching a string in regex

Tags: c#, regex

This is the string that I want to match:

```
"t=0, data=00 00 00 f1 00 00 00 00".
```

The following works:

- `(@"^(t)=[0-9]+,((\s[0-9A-F-a-f]{2}){8})")`
  matches:
  `"t=0, 00 00 00 f1 00 00 00 00"`
- `(@"^(t)=[0-9]+,\s\w+=")`
  matches:
  `"t=0, data="`

The following *doesn't* work:

- `(@"^(t)=[0-9]+,\s\w+=((\s[0-9A-F-a-f]{2}){8})")`
  doesn't match: 
  `"t=0, data=00 00 00 f1 00 00 00 00"`

Here is my code at the moment :

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^(t)=[0-9]+,\s\w+=((\s[0-9A-F-a-f]{2}){8})");
if(rgx.IsMatch(line.Trim())){
  //...
}
```

Comment: Can you add more example of good match? Or is there only a single match? If there is a single match you might want to look at a function that only find a string and not use regex.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: Hugo Dozois - the string is longer, but there I had a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your needs you could use the following regex :

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(^t=[0-9]+,[a-z ]+=([A-Fa-f0-9]{2} ?){8})");
if(rgx.IsMatch(line.Trim())){
    //...
}
```

So:

- `^t=[0-9]+,[a-z ]+=` matches everything before the hex numbers.
- `([A-Fa-f0-9]{2} ?){8}` matches 8 groups of 2 hex character followed or not by a space.

Everything is included in the `$1` variable as the enclosing parenthesis matches the full line.

Answer (score 1):

`^(t)=[0-9]+,\s\w+=([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}(\s|$)){8}` will do the trick.
you placed a whitespace character after each two digits, but because the last two digits don't have a whitespace after them the regex won't match. Now the regex engine can choose between a whitespace character or an end of string.

Edit: changed word boundary to end of string

Edit2: also, take a look at this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Answer (score 0):

for (\s[0-9A-F-a-f]{2}) to match first pair of digits just after = sign you need to have a space between the = sign and first digit. But it seems you dont.

Also is (\s[0-9A-F-a-f]{2}) correct?. I think you need to delete the '-' between F and a.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to match the pattern:

```
t=0, data=00 00 00 f1 00 00 00 00
```

I have made some assumptions:

- there can be any number of digits following `t=`
- there are 8 groups of two hex digits following the `data=`
- you need the data in a match group

Then this pattern will work:

```
^t=[0-9]++,\s*+data=(?<data>(?:[0-9a-f]{2}\s?){8})$
```

A test in Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    final String data = "t=0, data=00 00 00 f1 00 00 00 00";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^t=[0-9]++,\\s*+data=(?<data>(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}\\s?){8})$");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
        System.out.println(matcher.group("data"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
t=0, data=00 00 00 f1 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 f1 00 00 00 00
```